# How to Change background Color while Hovering in Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, highlighting

I am building a eclipse plugin with custom editor. I have implemented text hovering functionality in which user hover on some text then that text will be shown on tooltip like javadocs.

Now i want to change the background color of that hovering text in editor. How i can implement that? I tried some code. But i didn't working.

```java
Color blueColor = new Color(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(),0,0,255);
textViewer.setTextColor(blueColor, startRegion, finalStr.length(), false);
```

Here finalStr is a String that i will get when i hover on some text. I want to change the background and foreground color of finalStr.

Comment: Does your editor use `IPresentationRepairer` or is it just plain text?

Comment: It is just a plain text.

Comment: Seems to work for me doing a quick test. Is `startRegion` a valid offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question. Above code wasn't working for me because i was accessing it outside SWT thread. So i have to make a new thread and write code in that thread. Following is the code i used to make it work.

```java
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void run() {
    try {Thread.sleep(10); } catch (Exception e) { }
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
          textViewer.invalidateTextPresentation();
          Color lightColor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);
          Color blueColor=new Color(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(),0,0,255);
          TextPresentation presentation = new TextPresentation();
          TextAttribute attr = new TextAttribute(blueColor,lightColor , 0);
          presentation.addStyleRange(new StyleRange(startRegion, finalStr.length(), attr.getForeground(),attr.getBackground()));
          textViewer.changeTextPresentation(presentation, true); 
    }
   });
  }
}).start();
```